# History of determinism

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, determinism

Does determinism have its roots in logic? When was determinism as a discrete discipline first recorded? I am just interested in the historical aspect at the moment.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism#History) states: "The first full-fledged notion of determinism appears to originate with the Stoics, as part of their theory of universal causal determinism.[38]" Is this not satisfactory for some reason?

Comment: I agree with the comment above. The concept is no older than the Greek pre-Socratic natural philosophers.

Comment: [Here](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/history-of-the-study-of-indeterminism-in-classical-mechanics) is an insightful answer given by @Conifold to a question on indeterminism in classical mechanics, in which Conifold also gives the 19th century origins of the concept of determinism as applied in science. This was probably the next milestone after the Stoic treatment of determinism.